# How to edit an unbound cell in a bound DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So I have a DataGrid bound to a data source (using ADO.NET), I created a new local column (it doesn't need to exist in database). 
I do some calculations and then put the results in that column.
Now, I know how to edit/access the bound cells via DataSet, but I don't know how to do it for the cells of that new column because it's not in the DataSet.
I want to iterate each row and edit the cell value of the new column. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who comes to this page, adding the following attribute to my `DataGrid`'s declaration did the trick for me:

```
SelectedItemBinding="{Binding /}"
```

For more information, please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615113/datagrid-how-to-manipulate-selected-item/18626727#18626727).