# DataGrid: How to manipulate selected item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

This must be simple but all my searching leads to binding-based solutions, which is not my case.

I have a `DataGrid` in which there is a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. This column's `ItemsSource` property is bound to a string array. I use a loop in the startup to set the `SelectedItem` of this column for each row of my DataGrid through this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgResults.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var x = dgResults.GetCell(i, 0).Content as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;
    x.SelectedItem = "One of the items of my array";
}
```

`GetCell()` is an extension method that I grabbed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464704/get-row-in-datagrid).

Now the problem is that when I click on a particular cell of this column, the dropdown appears in the cell and is correctly populated with all array items, but the dropdown's current text is empty, i.e. it doesn't automatically select the corresponding item from the dropdown. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Here is the relevant portion of my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgResults" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{StaticResource ReminderValues }" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As you can see, this particular column is not bound to an underlying `DataColumn` or something, although the whole DataGrid IS bound to a DataTable. Also, I know for sure that this is not a spelling issue.

Comment: It would help if you showed the relevant XAML code. My guess is you should create a binding for `SelectedItem`, rather than try to set it manually as you're trying at the moment.

Comment: Updated my question with more info. Please check.

Comment: @dotNET hopefully my answer will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out after taking some sleep. If you've got an UNBOUND `DataGridComboBoxColumn` in your grid (i.e. the column doesn't bind to a column in the underlying data source) and its `ItemsSource` property is bound to an array or something, you must add the following to your `DataGrid` declaration:

```
SelectedItemBinding="{Binding /}"
```

The slash character (/) above represents the current item itself, which is what we want our SelectedItem to be.

Now my DataGrid displays values correctly and once the cell gets focus, the ComboBox appears with the correct value selected.

Answer (score 0):

To test whether your code example actually works or not, try changing it to this and running your application:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgResults.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var x = dgResults.GetCell(i, 0).Content as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;
    x.SelectedIndex = comboBoxItemsSource.Items.Count - 1;
}
```

If the `ComboBox`es all have the last option selected, then this code works well. If not, then you have a problem. If it does work, the problem *could* be that you didn't *exactly* match the `string` in the `Items` collection that you want to be selected... remember, if even one character is in the wrong case, it won't match and therefore won't be selected.

If the above code does *not* work, then maybe you need to test your `GetCell` method further... have you put a break point in this `for` loop to verify that `x` is indeed the correct cell?

Comment: do you really mean `dgResults.Items.Count - 1` above?

Comment: Yes... why wouldn't I mean that? I'm setting the `SelectedIndex` to the index of the last item as a test because this will eliminate the possibility of the question author miss-matching a `string` when setting the `SelectedItem` property.

Comment: mmm... dgResult.Items.Count could be a large number (the number of records being shown in the grid), whereas my ComboBox only has a dozen or so items.

Comment: Oh I see... in that case, no I didn't mean to use that collection... I meant to use your collection of `string` values that goes into your `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't bother another cast you may could do this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgResults.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var x = dgResults.GetCell(i, 0).Content as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;

    var array = x.ItemsSource as string[] ;
    x.SelectedItem = array.Where(s => s == "B").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

EDIT:
ok this should work now

working sample:
**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="simpletest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="ReminderValues" Type="sys:String">
            <sys:String>A</sys:String>
            <sys:String>B</sys:String>
            <sys:String>C</sys:String>
            <sys:String>D</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
        <x:Array x:Key="count" Type="sys:String">
            <sys:String>A</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dgResults" ItemsSource="{StaticResource count}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{StaticResource ReminderValues }" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="428,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**CS**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgResults.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var x = dgResults.GetCell(i, 0).Content as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;

            var array = x.ItemsSource as string[];
            x.SelectedItem = array.Where(s => s == "B").FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```